how to compare an array of strings with a string entered by the user
Let's say I have an array of strings.
string ban[3] = {"Ben","Lina", "Adam"};
I ask the user to enter his name.How to make sure that the check was not exactly accurate, but for example, if you write not just Adam, but Adam1990, then it was not missed
I thought about creating an array of characters and checking everything by characters, but it's long and probably pointless

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr

Presumably then, you don't want to miss "adam" and need to make same-case versions of both the array string and the input string, and use strstr() both ways round. But why do you want to be loose with a user name? It is what it is, but in the case of Stackoverflow my user name might be found without a space in comments.

Do you mean fuzzy matching?

Do you want Adam1990 and 123adam to be able to sign in to Adam's account, if they happen to have the same password?

Use Trie data structure and then add isbanned = true or false;

When it comes to names, you are probably wasting time doing this. What other criteria do you have to compare users? (Hopefully this isn’t just a homework problem where you are trying to go beyond the prompt. If it isn’t, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


Read the user input string with fgets(),  Lop off the optional trialing '\n'.

Using an upper bound for a name, maybe a few hundred letters? Use fgets() to read the line and memcmp(), or strncmp() to compare the strings.  Test the next character after an initial match.
#define NAME_LENGHT_MAX 600
//                     name           extra \n  \0
#define LINE_SIZE_MAX (NAME_LENGHT_MAX + 1 + 1 + 1)

char user_input[LINE_SIZE_MAX];
if (fgets(user_input, LINE_SIZE_MAX, stdin)) {
  size_t len = strlen(user_input);
  // Lop off optional \n
  if (len > 0 && user_input[len-1] == '\n') {
    user_input[--len] = '\0';  
  }

  // Check if name initially matches.
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    size_t target_length = strlen(ban[i]));
    if (memcmp(user_input, ban[i], target_length) == 0) {
      if (user_input[target_length] = '\0') {
        // Exact match
        ...
      // If not an exact match TBD to determine is partial initial match is OK.
      // Perhaps the first non-match should be a non-letter?
      } else if (isalpha(user_input[target_length])) {
        // No match
      } else {
        // Close enough partial match
      }
    }
  }

Additional code to detect over long lines of input by testing len.

This becomes messy very fast: what about names like “Jörgen”?

@Dúthomhas  With ASCII, not messy. "what about names like “Jörgen”" --> You have entered the twilight zone.  Things get messy outside ASCII, for then we need to discern the encoding and the lexigraphical standard used to sort. - something very locale specific.  It might be UTF8, maybe not.
